# env is not working but echo displays the variables

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, zsh

Completely perplexed at this behaviour.

`env` is not displaying the variable but `echo` is displaying it.

i was routinely testing a .env file import using `env | grep VAR` but somehow it did not show right after i sourced it. that got me thinking.

Here are the steps i am using to get the problem.

```
$ cat >.env
TARXAN=wat
^D
$ . .env
$ echo $TARXAN
wat
$ env | grep TARXAN

$
```

i have zsh with oh-my-zsh. don't have any dotenv plugins enabled. would appreciate any help.
i am in kubuntu 20.04.

I have also tested this entire setup in xterm. same result.

Comment: You need to `export TARXAN`.  Otherwise it is just a shell variable, not an environment variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not displayed by `env` because `TARXAN` is not an environment variable, i.e. it has not been exported. It's a shell variable only.

Comment: +1. `env` isn't a shell builtin -- it's a standalone program -- so it can't know about shell variables (which live inside Zsh), only about environment variables (which are passed to invoked programs).

Comment: any other way than to put export in front of every line.

Comment: `eval "$(sed 's#^#export #' .env)"` should do the job.

Comment: Don't use `eval`; just use `setopt ALL_EXPORT` (or `set -a`, which would work in `bash` or `zsh`) to enable auto-exporting of names being assigned to. `set -a; . .env; set +a`.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `.env` files are not necessarily assumed to be shell scripts, and simply sourcing one may not produce the expected value. (For example, compare https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#rules with shell evaluation rules.)